# Is there an official Chinese handwriting input method for Android?

Tags: keyboard, chinese-language

I searched for some page about Chinese handwriting input, but on my Android 7.1, I only see Pinyin, and it shows the following:

[image]

On some page, such as https://eastasiastudent.net/china/mandarin/handwriting-practice-android/

I do see

[image]

with the bottom right panel suitable for handwriting input. So my Android 7.1 doesn't have it... and going to Settings, I only see the Google Pinyin input (Pinyin means "assemble sound" or phonetics).

But that page seems to suggests the handwriting panel can be obtained by Pinyin input.

Is there a way to have an official Chinese handwriting input method for Android?

Comment: That 2nd image doesn't look like an official input method either, since Google Input doesn't offer T9 layout. Just use 3rd-party ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it: it is an app in the Google Play store called Google Handwriting Input.

It doesn't say it has Chinese Handwriting Input there right now but it in fact does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Chinese. and I use iFly(xun fei, also讯飞) input method, may be the best input method for inputting Chinese(whatever handwriting or voice inputting or using the keyboard).

[image]